# Is there any way to convert text file to LaTEX using perl?

Tags: perl

I basically want to convert a text file to pdf and other formats. So i am thinking if i could first convert it into LaTEX then i can go ahead with pdf conversion. Is this feasible?

Comment: When you searched for "convert text to pdf," is LaTeX really the top solution you found? Have you considered using something that will do the conversion directly, like a2pdf or text2pdf? You wouldn't have to write any code at all.

Comment: Do you require some sort of pretty formatting?  There are many light markup languages like ReStructured text, markdown etc which allow you to format headlines etc. with a minimum of fuss.  There are then good translators from many of these formats to LaTeX if that is your formatting platform of choice.

Comment: @RobKennedy, well actually i need to convert the text into pdf or other formats as well.So LaTEX came to my mind as i have done some conversions from latex to other formats.We are basically working on a perl library so i want if somehow i can convert the text to LaTEX then i can take care of the other part.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~tjenness/Pod-LaTeX-0.60/lib/Pod/LaTeX.pm

Comment: Why do you want to use Perl> Do you really care what tool you use?

Comment: look at multimarkdown project: http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/

Comment: @briandfoy, yes i do, because as i said i am working as a part of a large team which is building a perl library. So we are supposed to do this in perl.

Comment: I really dislike that one can only vote to close, then vote to reopen. I would have voted NOT to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say that you are familiar with LaTeX, you know that there are only a few [special characters](http://www.cespedes.org/blog/85/how-to-escape-latex-special-characters). Aside from that, regular text and LaTeX markup are very similar; it isn't until you get to formatting and figures and math that it gets more involved. That said it wouldn't take much to setup a few regular expressions to escape the incoming text.

Edit:

It would seem that someone has already made such a module: [TeX::Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?TeX%3a%3aEncode). Going to try it out myself too. There is a dependency problem, you must manually install `Test::Pod::Coverage` before you can install `TeX::Encode`; yes that is embarrassing.